# how to find next positive bigger palindrome without using loops or recursive?

Tags: javascript

I need to find next positive bigger palindrome, but I'm not allowed to use loops or recursive.

For example:

```
getNext(1002); //return 1111
```

How else can I find it?

Comment: So ... the solution you are going to present to your teacher is "I didn't use a loop or a recursive function, I asked on the Internet"? Your teacher may have had something else in mind.

Comment: @usr2564301, seems legit. :)

Comment: I don't need a solution in form of code. I need a way except for those that I indicated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, think about it. You have a specific case, where your palindrome is a number. Numbers are easy work. If you have 1002, you may take the first n/2 numbers and reverse it, so: 10_01, this is lesser, so you add one in the first: `10 + 1 = 11`. This gives you the base for the next one. So, you reverse this and gets: `11_11`.

This is a simple algorithm, so the code is with you.

**Edit:**

I think is pretty obvious, but it is better to say. If the number has an odd number of digits, the center digit will be the same or the same plus one. Anyway, I think you got the idea.

Comment: I understood your algorithm. Thanks a lot)

Comment: @T.Nelson, if you solved it, please post code...Nice task, btw, not so trivial homework (especially when arguments are some specific numbers, you will see which ones;)), for sure. :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution of this task which I implemented with help of Fabiano's algorithm. I know it's unreadable but it works)

```
function getNextPalindrome(number) {
  let result;
  let nextNum = String(number + 1);
  let leftSide;
  let middle;
  let rightSide;
  let divider = Math.floor(Number(nextNum.length / 2));
  let amountOfNumbers = middle = nextNum.split('');

  if (number < 10) {
    result = 11;
  } else if (amountOfNumbers.length % 2 === 0) {
    leftSide = nextNum.slice(0, divider);
    rightSide = leftSide.split('').reverse().join('');
    result = Number(leftSide + rightSide);
    if (result < nextNum) {
      leftSide = String(Number(nextNum.slice(0, divider)) + 1);
      rightSide = leftSide.split('').reverse().join('');
      result = Number(leftSide + rightSide);
    }
  } else if (amountOfNumbers.length % 2 !== 0) {
    leftSide = nextNum.slice(0, divider);
    middle = Number(middle[Math.floor(middle.length / 2)]);
    rightSide = leftSide.split('').reverse().join('');
    result = Number(leftSide + middle + rightSide);
    if (result < nextNum) {
      middle = middle + 1;
      if (middle === 10) {
        middle = 0;
        leftSide = String(Number(nextNum.slice(0, divider)) + 1);
        rightSide = leftSide.split('').reverse().join('');
        result = Number(leftSide + middle + rightSide);
      } else {
        leftSide = String(Number(nextNum.slice(0, divider)));
        rightSide = leftSide.split('').reverse().join('');
        result = Number(leftSide + middle + rightSide);
      }
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```